# Disable Centering of User location Google maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, center

I am working with Google maps iOS SDK. Every time I scroll around the map it brings me back to the user location. I am trying to figure how to disable centering to user location so that I can scroll around the map and look for more places. Will appreciate any pointers.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some code that centers to the user's location everytime you get a locationUpdate call in your viewController? Google Map iOS SDK doesn't center to the user's location when you pan the map by default.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it adding [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; to CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation